# Два окна WinMain в двух потоках std::thread

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не создаются два окна.

Вот простой код:

Создаю отдельную функцию my_func_win_main, в которой создаю поток и в потоке вызываю стандартную функцию создания окна.

И далее из main вызываю первый функцию my_func_win_main() - создается окно, все классно.

И второй раз вызывается функция my_func_win_main() - а вот при втором вызове, второго окна не создаётся. Но я не могу понять почему.

PS: Как видно, main() не завершается после вызова двух функций, а спит в ожидании, когда создастся второе окно, но оно не создается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND   hWnd, UINT   message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;


    if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        HDC my_hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); 


        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
    }



    if (message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        std::cout << "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" << std::endl;
    }
    if (message == WM_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        std::cout << "WM_LBUTTONUP" << std::endl;
    }
    if (message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        std::cout << "WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK" << std::endl;
    }




    if (message == WM_CLOSE) 
    {
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);  
    }

    if (message == WM_DESTROY)  
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }


    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 


}





std::string My_create_window_()
{


    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(NULL); 

    if (hInstance == NULL)
    {
        return "GetModuleHandleA == NULL:" + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    WNDCLASSEX My_WNDCLASSEX;      

    wchar_t My_lpszClassName[] = L"My_Clas_Windows";

    My_WNDCLASSEX.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);       
    My_WNDCLASSEX.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;   
    My_WNDCLASSEX.lpfnWndProc = WndProc2;             
    My_WNDCLASSEX.cbClsExtra = 0;                    
    My_WNDCLASSEX.cbWndExtra = 0;                    
    My_WNDCLASSEX.hInstance = hInstance;            
    My_WNDCLASSEX.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);   
    My_WNDCLASSEX.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);          
    My_WNDCLASSEX.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 0);     
    My_WNDCLASSEX.lpszMenuName = NULL;                        
    My_WNDCLASSEX.lpszClassName = L"My_Clas_Windows";                    
    My_WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm = LoadIcon(My_WNDCLASSEX.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);  
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    int result_RegisterClassEx = RegisterClassEx(&My_WNDCLASSEX);  



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (result_RegisterClassEx == 0)  
    {
        return "Error: RegisterClassEx == 0:" + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     //Функция создания окна
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        My_WNDCLASSEX.lpszClassName,                    
        L"My_main_window东",                                     
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                             
        255,                                            
        0,                                             
        1000,                                             
        500,                                            
        NULL,                                            
        NULL,                                            
        My_WNDCLASSEX.hInstance,                         
        NULL                                             
    );
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (hWnd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        return "Error: CreateWindow == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:" + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    ///////////////////////////////////
    ShowWindow(hWnd,                          
        SW_SHOWDEFAULT);  //nCmdShow             
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    ///////////////////////////////////






    ////////////////////////////////////////
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))  
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);   
        DispatchMessage(&msg);    
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////


    return std::to_string((int)msg.wParam);

}













void my_func_win_main()
{

my_thread(My_create_window_);
    my_thread.detach();


}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
 
my_func_win_main();
 
my_func_win_main();

    Sleep(50000);
 
}
```

Comment: думаю, что правильный ответ - они не успевают. Ведь после того, как две функции my_func_win_main отработали, Ваше приложение просто закрывается и все.

Comment: @KoVadim, к сожалению нет. Я немого скорректировал код main.cpp - сразу забыл одну строчку скопировать. Main() после вызова двух функций не завершается - у меня там стоит  Sleep(50000);

Comment: *"второго окна не создаётся"* - в вопросе не приведен ни код создания окна, ни какие-либо пояснения, в связи с чем вы решаете, что окно не создается. Вызов detach является ошибкой.

Comment: @user7860670, очевидно в связи с тем, что я его не вижу визуально. Код создания окна я специально не добавил, чтобы не захломлять визуально вопрос.

Comment: Это ни разу не очевидно. Более того, если вы его не видите, то это ни разу не показатель того, что оно не создалось. Собственно так как код создания окна не приведен, то нет ни малейших оснований предполагать, что окно сразу создается видимым.

Comment: @user7860670, по каким причинам, тогда первое окно я вижу ?

Comment: Я же не телепат, откуда я знаю, что вы там видите. Сначала приводите [mcve], а потом можно будет о чем-то говорить.

Comment: @user7860670, а я четко написал, что вижу Одно созданное окно и в телепаты Вас не записывал.

Comment: а потом окажеться, что ошибки никто не проверяет, и там просто нельзя создать второе окно, потому что оно имеет такой же id.

Comment: Вполне может быть, однако если не приведен [mcve], то проверить это читающие не смогут. А ответ может оказаться правильным лишь случайно.

Comment: @user7860670, скорректировал до полностью рабочего примера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытка повторно зарегистрировать оконный класс с тем же именем, пока предыдущий еще жив, обречена на провал.

Тем более, что потом идет изящная конструкция

```
 if (result_RegisterClassEx == 0)  
    {
        return "Error: RegisterClassEx == 0:" + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
```

возвращающая бесхозную строку и содержащая недостижимую печать в cout

Comment: похоже, мой хрустальных шар ещё достаточно прозрачный:)

Comment: @user7860670, вы оказались полностью правы, я балда.

Comment: @Optimus1 Неигнорируйте предупреждения компилятора. Он же наверняка ругался на недостижимый код `std::cout << "error" << std::endl;`.

Comment: @user7860670, не, VS2019 - не выдало ни одного предупреждения.

Comment: @Optimus1 ¿Может они у вас и не включены? Убедитесь, что в настройках проекта в С/C++ → General → Warning level стоит `/W4`, С/C++ → General → Treat warning as errors стоит `/WX`, С/C++ → Language → Conformance mode стоит `/permissive-`, Code analysis → General все стоит Yes.