# Не получается передать строку или ее адрес в памяти из dll C++ в клиент C#, только char или int

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Как передавать что то большее чем char или int, например строку?, через указатель на область памяти не получается:
состав dll:
file string_emplary.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "string_emplary.h"
#include <iostream>

char* Emplary()
{
    char dest[8];
    const char* b = &"Emplary"[0];
    strcpy(dest, b);
    return dest;
}

int* int_a(){ int a = 10; int* p = &a;  return p; }
int int_b(){ int b = 357;  return b;}
char char_c(){ char c = 'c'; return c;}
```

file string_emplary.h

```
#pragma once
#ifdef string_emplary
#define string_emplary_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define string_emplary_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" string_emplary_API char* Emplary();
extern "C" string_emplary_API int* int_a();
extern "C" string_emplary_API int int_b();
extern "C" string_emplary_API char char_c();
```

принимающая сторона C#
file Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace import_from_cppdll
{
    public unsafe partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern char* Emplary();

        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int* int_a();

        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int int_b();

        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern char char_c();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private unsafe void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char p0 = *Emplary();    // garbage
            char p1 = ++*(Emplary()); // garbage
            char p2 = ++*(Emplary());// garbage
            int a0 = *int_a(); // garbage
            int* a1 = int_a();// 
             char* p00 = Emplary(); // here at the address is '\0'
            int b0 = int_b(); // 357 !!! it work!
            char c0 = char_c(); // 99'c' !!! it work!

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы работала передача по указателю нужно озаботится, чтобы время жизни объекта, на который тот указывает, не оказалось короче времени жизни указателя. Видимо при сборке .cpp предупреждения компилятора намеренно игнорировались.

Comment: включил /Wall, получил предупреждение:
Предупреждение C5039 "TpSetCallbackCleanupGroup": в функцию extern "C" с параметром -EHc были переданы указатель или ссылка на функцию, которая может вызвать исключение. Если эта функция вызовет исключение, может возникнуть неопределенное поведение. string_emplary D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winbase.h 7723

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342267/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-winmain-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-stdthread/1342287#comment2377102_1342287

Comment: После завершения работы функции локальные объекты перестают существовать. Такие как `dest` в функции `Emplary` и `a` в функции `int_a`. Указатели на эти объекты становятся невалидными — их больше нельзя использовать для доступа к значениям уничтоженных объектов. См.: [Как в С возвратить массив из функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/948544)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ответ на закрытое сообщение: [вот оно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141147/it-is-not-possible-to-transfer-a-string-or-its-address-in-memory-from-a-c-dll?noredirect=1#comment123989577_70141147). Проблема в том, что символы C ++ составляют 1 байт, а символы C# - 2 байта. Чтобы обойти это, используйте `wchar_t` в своей программе на C.

```
extern "C"
{
wchar_t dest[8];  /* return value must not be on the stack */

string_emplary_API wchar_t* Emplary()
{
    /* Wide string literals have a leading L */
    const wchar_t* b = L"Emplary";
    /* This is the wide string version of strcpy */
    wcscpy(dest, b);
    /* This value must not be on the stack */
    return dest;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Благодаря [@cup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1355101) окончательно все поправил:

dll: file string_emplary.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "string_emplary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void FillArrayInt(int a[], int n)
{
    const char* b = &"Emplary"[0];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
}

wchar_t* Emplary (wchar_t dest[])
{
    /* Wide string literals have a leading L */
    const wchar_t* b = L"Emplary";
    /* This is the wide string version of strcpy */
    wcscpy(dest, b);
    /* This value must not be on the stack */
    return dest;
}
```

file string_emplary.h

```
#pragma once
#ifdef string_emplary
#define string_emplary_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define string_emplary_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" string_emplary_API void FillArrayInt(int a[], int n);
extern "C" string_emplary_API wchar_t* Emplary(wchar_t dest[]);
```

C# file Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace import_from_cppdll
{
    public unsafe partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void FillArrayInt(int[] a, int n);
       
        
        [DllImport(@"D:\VLAD\C++\import_DLL\string_emplary\Debug\string_emplary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    
        public static extern char* Emplary(char[] incoming);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private unsafe void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int b = 8;
            int[] a = new int[8];
            FillArrayInt(a, b);
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                output += Convert.ToChar(a[i]); // "Emplary\0"  it work!!!
            }
                       
            var incoming = new char[8];          
            char* outBuf = Emplary(incoming);
            for (int i = 0; i < incoming.Length; i++)
            {
                incoming[i] = outBuf[i];
            }
            //  it work!!!

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пришлось только добавить переход по указателю `char* outBuf` который указывает на адрес первого двух байтного элемента, и считать подряд все восемь      элементов в выделенный для этого массив `var incoming = new char[8]; ` из памяти

Comment: Наверное возможно считывать например до нахождения первого символа `0'\0'`.  что таким образом будет задавать необходимый размер, если заранее не известно что это 8 как в данном примере?

Comment: The problem with using new is that you now have a memory leak.  Every time you call that routine, there will be an 8 byte memory leak.

Comment: @cup [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1355764/472403]

Comment: If memory has been allocated in C, it needs to be deallocated in C.  C# does not know anything about what you've done in C.  A simple way is to keep the memory allocated in a singly linked list and call the deallocate routine when you have finished.  Remember that your C# is unsafe i.e. memory management is handled by something else.

Answer (score -1):

ЭТО НЕ ОТВЕТ , А вопрос где здесь утечка памяти?? =) - I thought that in C# automatic garbage collection

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот чего вы все минусуете то? я просто не знаю как в комментарий картинку вставить, это типо коммент такой

Comment: А за что здесь ставить плюс? За картинку? И что-то непонятное? Проблема юзера в том что он передает у Азат ль на локальный буфер, который после вызова функции становится невалидным.

Comment: @Kotomi Это всего лишь ответ на комментарий  -"The problem with using new is that you now have a memory leak. Every time you call that routine, there will be an 8 byte memory leak. – 
cup
 2 часа назад" - здесь я скриншотом показал что не понял где утечка памяти то??? всего лишь на всего, это не ответ ? а коммент уж извини

Comment: @Kotomi  лучше объясни где там утечка и как ее пресечь, если не трудно )

Comment: На картинке никаких утечек памяти не показано.

Comment: И как мне вызвать процедуру освобождения, памяти после того как я заполнил `incoming`? что мне там в dll ке дописать нужно за процедуру

Comment: @user7860670 я так почемуто тоже подумал, тока чел пишет: типо -Если память была выделена в C, ее необходимо освободить в C. C# ничего не знает о том, что вы сделали в C. Простой способ - сохранить память, выделенную в односвязном списке, и вызвать процедуру освобождения, когда вы закончите. Помните, что ваш C# небезопасен, т.е. управление памятью обрабатывается чем-то другим

Comment: Он правильно пишет... Однако вместо вопроса в комментарии и/или в ответе - следует задать отдельный новый вопрос.

Comment: Тогда в новом вопросе буду использовать мой последний код , картинку экрана где нет утечки и  перевод комментария человека по имени cup. осталось только грамотно все сформулировать, что бы никого не злить. )